# Link a "System View" and an "Entity" from CRM Dynamics using Fetch XML

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, ssis-2012, fetchxml

I was trying to get some records by joining a "system view" and an entity from the same organization in MS dynamics using fetch XML (basically im doing this inside an ssis task) - it works if I try to join multiple entities OR different entities from the same ORG.

I'm not sure what code needs to be used in the "Link- entity" part to get the entity linked to system view. Below is the code im trying to workout

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format = "xml-platform" mapping = "logical" distinct = "true">
<entity name = "Contact">
<attribute name = "address1_line1"/>
<attribute name = "address1_city"/>         
<link-entity name="My system View" alias = "msv" to="contactid" from = "new_contactID" link-type="inner">  
 <attribute name = "Company"/>
</link-entity> 
</entity>
</fetch>
```

Question-  Instead of using the code     `<link-entity name="My system View" alias = "msv" to="contactid" from = "new_contactID" link-type="inner">`
what needs to done such that I link the entity "Contact" to the systemview "My system view" ?

Comment: why do you need systemview? I mean your end result is getting records from related/linked entity?
Why not create a Fetchxml with link entity fulfilling all your criteria and you will have all you data.
Any specific reason you are bound to systemview?

Answer (score 1):

You can only have entity as a linked entity in FetchXML. Seems like you are trying to build a parental reference with in the same entity contacts? If that is the case you have to add contact as a linked entity and add the conditions of that System View inside the linked entity element.

Example:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" >
    <entity name="Contact" >
        <attribute name="address1_line1" />
        <attribute name="address1_city" />
        <link-entity name="contact" alias="msv" to="contactid" from="new_contactID" link-type="inner" >
            <filter type="and" >
                <condition attribute="sysviewattrname" operator="eq" value="value" />
            </filter>
            <attribute name="Company" />
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Please note, I have manually modified the FetchXML so you might have to tweak it little bit in case it doesn't validate.

Comment: Thanks Khadim.. But I'm not looking to add/build a parental reference.. I'm trying to connect/link a "view" with a  "table" (In SQL) -- IN this case its a link between system view and an entity.

Comment: I think, in theory it is a parental reference, isn't it? If so, you may try creating a parental relationship in contact entity, fill in the parents of certain contacts and formulate your FetchXML accordingly.